# Multiple Binding Source Filters

Tags: c#

I have a simple database and I'm trying to make it searchable with multiple criteria. What I do not know is how to get the datagridview to filter using these various criteria all together. I'm doing it very messily I know with the if else statements. If I filter with the combobox, it will disregard all my other criteria. Here's my basic code:

```
if (StartDate < EndDate)
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Suggestion Date] >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND [Suggestion Date] <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", StartDate, EndDate);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmp) == false)
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("Employee like '%{0}%'", SearchEmp.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchSupv) == false)
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Supervisor] like '%{0 }%'", SearchSupv.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchAssigned) == false)
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Assigned To] like '%{0}%'", SearchAssigned.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
}
else if (comboBoxCompleted.Text == "Incomplete")
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Completed]='False'");
}
else if (comboBoxCompleted.Text == "Completed")
{
    employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Completed]='True'");
}
```

There has to be a much easier way to filter the results and I know I'm probably doing it in the worst way...ha.

Comment: You probably also need to add several filters for the same query, don't you ? What type is `employeeSuggestionsBindingSource`?

Comment: The datagrid is bound to an Access DB. If that's what you mean by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to build up your filter criteria with one or more predicates.  You can do this by composing multiple conditions together with `AND`:

```
string filter = null;

if (StartDate < EndDate)
{
    filter = CombineCriteria(
        filter,
        string.Format(
            "[Suggestion Date] >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND " + 
            "[Suggestion Date] <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#",
            StartDate,
            EndDate));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmp) == false)
{
    filter = CombineCriteria(
        filter,
        string.Format(
            "[Employee] LIKE '%{0}%'",
            SearchEmp.Trim().Replace("'", "''")));
}

// ... more filter conditions ...

if (comboBoxCompleted.Text == "Incomplete")
    filter = CombineCriteria(filter, "[Completed] = False");
else if (comboBoxCompleted.Text == "Completed")
    filter = CombineCriteria(filter, "[Completed] = True");

employeeSuggestionsBindingSource.Filter = filter;
```

Where `CombineCriteria()` is as follows:

```
private static string CombineCriteria(string oldCondition, string newCondition) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldCondition))
        return newCondition;

    return "(" + oldCondition+ ") AND (" + newCondition + ")";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. I hadn't come across a method like this or thought of adding one.